# Derivative of function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n, n\geqslant 2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How to compute the derivative for a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. for a function in one variable in $\mathbb{R}$ but in $\mathbb{R}^n, n\geq 2$?

Is this component-wise, i.e. writing $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots,f_n(x))\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f_i\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, 1\leq i\leq n$, then determining $f_i'(x)$ and just getting then
$$
f'(x)=(f_1'(x),\ldots,f_n'(x))?
$$

Comment: That's exactly right

Comment: And I guess it is the same with function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, say $n=2, m=3$, then we can write this as $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ with $f_i\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}, i=1,2,3$ and by multidim. calculus, we have that the derivative of each $f_i$ is given by $df_i(a)=(df_i(a)e_1,df_i(a)e_2,df_i(a)e_3)$ resp. $df(a)h=\sum_{v=1}^n \partial_vf_i(a)h_v$ such that as a whole we get that $f'(a)=\begin{pmatrix}df_1(a)\\df_2(a)\\df_3(a)\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Right, so if $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, then $f'(a)$ should be an $m \times n$ matrix.

Comment: And it's called the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

In general the derivative of a function
$$f = (f_1(x_1,\dots,x_m),\dots, f_n(x_1,\dots,x_m)): \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$$
is defined to be the matrix 
$$\left( \frac{\partial f_j }{\partial x_i} \right) _{i,j}$$
In your case where $m=1$, this is just
$ (f_1'(x),\dots,f_n'(x)) $.